# How to avoid "Derefenrecing possible nullpointer" warning

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I get a "Dereferencing possible null pointer" warning in my IDE for line:

```
double tmpTermCoeff = tmpTerm.getCoeff();
```

I'm not sure how to solve this warning with the following code. If I replace "null" with "new Term()" it works but feels redundant or wrong since I create it right after in the while loop.

```
while(!tmpList.isEmpty()){
    Iterator<Term> iter = tmpList.iterator();

    Term tmpTerm = null;
    if(iter.hasNext()){
        tmpTerm = new Term(iter.next());
        iter.remove();                
    }

    while(iter.hasNext()){
        if(condition){
            double tmpTermCoeff = tmpTerm.getCoeff();
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
    simpleP.addTerm(tmpTerm);
}
```

Comment: You only initialize `tmpTerm` if `iter.hasNext()`, so technically, there is a chance that the `if` is not entered and thus `tmpTerm` is `null`.

Comment: A remark on your code: your logic seems messed up to me. For one, the two nested `while`-loops seem redundant and I have a feeling they can be replaced with one single loop. For another, you add `tmpTerm` to `simpleP`, AFTER `iter.hasNext() == false`, i.e. `tmpTerm.isEmpty()`... so you add an empty list to `simpleP`.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I don't think I need that first if statement and just put everything in the second while loop.

Comment: @Turing85 I believe I do need the two while loops in my case or maybe a recursive method would be better but basically, I'm adding terms which have a matching variable (I have removed some code to simplify my initial question). So given this list, I need to add matching variables [1a^2,2,3a,4a^2,9a,-2a]. So I check the first one (first loop), remove it from list then go through the list again to check for matching variables (second loop) and remove them if matching and restart until list is empty.

Comment: I think the compiler is right but if you are sure it can't be null: @SuppressWarnings("null")

Comment: the other possiblity is : "if(condition && (null != tmpTerm) )"

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!tmpList.isEmpty()){
    Iterator<Term> iter = tmpList.iterator();

    Term tmpTerm = null;
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        tmpTerm = iter.next();
        if(condition){
            double tmpTermCoeff = tmpTerm.getCoeff();
        }
    }
    simpleP.addTerm(tmpTerm);
}
```

Comment: If you have to ask, is it actually an answer?